# Knock-out tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics

50 challenging problems in probability question 17, "Twin Knights".

Knock out tournament structure with $2^n$ players. They are equally matched and beat each other with probability $1/2$. What is the probability that any two, say $A, B$, meet at some point during the tournament?

I don't know how to think about this question. The probability they meet in the first match is $\frac{1}{2^n - 1}$. The probability they meet in the second but not the first is $\frac{2}{2^n - 1} \times \frac{1}{4}$. The first term in the multiplication is the possible places B can come to play A in the second round, and the second is the probability they both beat their first round opponents. Next for the third round I get $\frac{4}{2^n - 1} \times \frac{1}{16}$. Now extending this pattern, I will try summing over all the values from $1$ to $n$ to get the desired probability. Summing the GP here gives me $1$. The expected correct answer was $1/2^{n-1}$.

Why didn't it work and what's the right way to think about this problem?

Comment: Your answer, $1$, is clearly false, even for $n=2$.  Just work through your argument line by line with $n=2$ to find the error.

Comment: Note:  There's probably a more clever way to get at the correct answer, but a straight forward induction works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^n-1$ matches in total and $\frac122^n(2^n-1)$ total possible matches. So the probability that you're looking for is:
$P=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}=\frac1{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: The way that this answer wrote players $A$ and $B$ completely out of the story is simultaneously scary and beautiful

Comment: I guess your argument is: A vs B is just one of the $\frac{1}{2} 2^n(2^n - 1)$ possible matches, and of those only $2^n - 1$ possible matches are lucky enough to become an actual match. So the probability that 'A vs B' becomes an actual match is therefor what you write.

Comment: First I thought there was an hidden assumption in this argument that the probabilities for the various potential matches of becoming an actual match are independent (which they are not). But on closer scrutiny there is no such assumption, just a symmetry argument. Very nice